# Does ZipArchive load entire zip file into memory

Tags: c#

If I stream a zip file like so:

```
using var zip = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
using var sr = new StreamReader(zip.Entries[0].Open());
var line = sr.ReadLine(); //etc..
```

Am I streaming the zip file entry or is it loading the entire zip file into memory then I am streaming the uncompressed file?

Comment: If you need to know then you're doing it wrong.  The underlying open source C library is ancient, one of its long-term maintainer was a college buddy of mine.  Helped me get prepped for my driving exam in his 2CV.  Ah, good times, 64KB was good enough for everybody.  I did fail the exam :)

Comment: Depends on file size and stream buffers setup. You may easily track [`FileStream.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.position?view=netframework-4.8). In general: No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the `fileStream` was created. Was it created from a file on disk? If so, then `ZipArchive` will read from disk as it needs data. It won't put the entire thing in memory then read it. That would be incredibly inefficient.

I have a bunch of experience in this... I worked on a project where I had to unarchive 25 GB. Zip files. .NET's `ZipArchive` was very quick and very memory efficient.

You can have `MemoryStream`s that contain data that `ZipArchive` can read from, so you aren't limited to just Zip files on disk.

Here is a slightly efficient way to unzip a `ZipArchive`:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "MyDirectoryToExtractTo"));

var filesToExtract = _zip.Entries.Where(x =>
                                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) &&
                                        !x.FullName.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal));

foreach(var x in filesToExtract)
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(di.FullName, x.FullName));
    
    if (!fi.Directory.Exists) { fi.Directory.Create(); }
    
    using (var i = x.Open())
    using (var o = fi.OpenWrite())
    {
        i.CopyTo(o);
    }
}
```

This will extract all the files to `C:\ProgramData\MyDirectoryToExtractTo\` keeping directory structure.

If you'd like to see how `ZipArchive` was implemented to verify, take a [look here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/MS/Internal/IO/Zip/ZipArchive.cs,040dfbf7c78aba7a).

Comment: Thanks for explanation! It is a filestream from a multipart form request to my api endpoint.  The framework I am using prepares it so not 100% sure but I think it streams as it uploads.  I am trying to read the file as its uploaded but don't want to nuke the servers ram if lots of people use upload at same time.

Comment: @Guerrilla -- If it's coming from an upload via Web, there are certain semantics IIS follows. For example, if the zip file is small (I don't know the limitation), it will give you a memory stream once it finishes uploading. But, once it exceeds a certain size, IIS will save it to disk and then give you a file stream. Regardless, IIS will optimize your stream for you so you don't have to worry about it. I have transferred multiple-GB Zip files via Web uploads and extracted right from the stream and had no problems.

Comment: Usually the zip file listing metadata is at the end of the file. So the `ZipArchive` may need to seek forwards and backwards. Something a HTTP POST stream cannot do. So the content will need to be buffered somewhere.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - I'm pretty sure you don't get access to the file stream until it's fully uploaded.

Comment: Would it be better to use gzip instead of zip?

Comment: @Guerrilla -- if you are only doing 1 file, then yes... GZip is extremely optimized format for compressing one single file. I you need to do multiple files, Zip would be your guy... Or you could do tar.gz... Tar "glues" all the files together into 1 file, then GZip semantics work at that point. But I don't believe .NET handles Tar files, but there are 3rd party files that do.. like Sharp Compress.